# SIGABRT error CPP receiving data from rabbitmq server

Tags: c++, boost, rabbitmq, sigabrt

I'm trying to create 2 c++ application, one is a gui interface that sends commands and the other is a slave which invoke commands. I set a rabbitmq server between the 2 app to establish an asynchronous communication between both apps. This the code of the receiver as the publisher works fine.

```
// main.cpp

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "cmd_ctl.h"
#include "cmd_handler.h"
#include "uart_handler.h"
#include "receiver.h"


int main() {


    CommandInvoker *invoker = new CommandInvoker;
    CommandHandler *handler = new CommandHandler;


    Receiver *receiver = new Receiver;

    // machanism to retreive or to store
    while(1) {
        std::cout << "Wainting for command...\n";
            receiver->revceiveRawCommand("hello_queue");
        }

    delete invoker;
    delete handler;
```

```
// receiver.h
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <SimpleAmqpClient/SimpleAmqpClient.h>
#include "cmd_ctl.h"

class Receiver {
    public:
        Receiver(const std::string hostname="localhost",
                const int port=5672,
                const std::string username="guest",
                const std::string password="guest",
                const std::string virtualHost="/");

        ~Receiver() {};

        void revceiveRawCommand(std::string);
        void commandCallback(std::string, CommandInvoker*, CommandHandler*);
        inline void setConnection(AmqpClient::Channel::ptr_t connection) { this->connection = connection; };

    private:
        AmqpClient::Channel::ptr_t connection;

};
```

```
// receiver.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "receiver.h"


Receiver::Receiver(std::string hostname, int port, std::string username, std::string password, std::string virtualHost) {
    AmqpClient::Channel::ptr_t conncetion = AmqpClient::Channel::Create(
            hostname, port, username, password, virtualHost
        );
    this->setConnection(connection);

}

void Receiver::revceiveRawCommand(std::string queue) {
    try {
        this->connection->DeclareQueue(queue, false, true, false, false);
        AmqpClient::Envelope::ptr_t envelope;

        connection->BasicConsume(queue, "", true, false, false);
        while(true) {
            connection->BasicConsumeMessage(envelope, 0);

            if (envelope) {
                std::string message = envelope->Message()->Body();
                // this->commandCallback(message);
            }
        }

    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void Receiver::commandCallback(std::string message, CommandInvoker* invoker, CommandHandler* handler) {
    // Get the message attribute inside a vector
    std::istringstream iss(message);
    std::vector<std::string> commands;
    std::string command;

    while(iss>> command) {
        commands.push_back(command);
    }

    // clean the message vector
    std::string commandName = commands.front();
    commands.erase(commands.begin());
    invoker->create_command(handler, commandName, commands);
    invoker->executeCommand();


}
```

I'm using a rabbitmq library for cpp which depends on the boost::asio library to create an asynchronous communication between two binaries.

I'm getting the error of SIGABRT in the `receiver->receiveCommand("hello_queue");` line in the main function indicating this error

```
  /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:784: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = AmqpClient::Channel; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = AmqpClient::Channel*]: Assertion px != 0' failed.
fish: Job 1, './DJIN-2' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Comment: Tactical note: It looks like you're coming into C++ from C#, Java, or a similar language.  You're going to have to forget a lot of the `new`-type thinking to write effective C++ code. I strongly recommend getting a good intermediate-level C++ text (because I'm assuming you do know how to program and don't need to learn that again) to brush up on the language differences before you go too much further and build up a lot of pseudo-C++ code you'll regret having to maintain.

Comment: similar to above, `this->setConnection(connection);` should be done in the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), not in a setter called inside the constructor. Do you really want to have a setter for this? It allows the holder of the object to do some potentially very stupid things.

Comment: Why I'm bring up these side details: I'm unravelling your code to see how you got what looks like a `shared_ptr` to null.

Comment: Side note: Have you run the program in a debugger yet?  The debugger should stop dead at the assert and give you a backtrace you can inspect so you can see how the program got into such a dire state. I'd do it myself, the example looks complete, but I don't have the libraries and other infrastructure to duplicate your environment.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `conncetion` is valid? I''m having trouble googling up documentation on `AmqpClient::Channel::Create`, but often a pointer-returning create function will return null on error.

Comment: The thing is that function works fine, I already tried it in the publisher code and it returns a shared_ptr like you said and it create a connection to the rabbitmq server and handles sending data to it.

Comment: What part of the code that you think is pseudo. Please do not hesitate to roast the code I need every advise to learn c++

Comment: By pseudo I mean the sort of code I wrote for about 3 years after coming into C++ thinking what I knew of C and Java would be enough. A decade later I'm still finding bits of code that makes me cringe. The first thing that stands out is there should be no need to `CommandInvoker *invoker = new CommandInvoker;` and then have to `delete` it a few lines later. `CommandInvoker invoker;` should do everything you need and it's 100% automated. Consider `new` to be a low-level tool you only use when you're working on the low-level infrastructure work like writing your own specialized container.

Comment: [Here's a good page of guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) Yes it's huge, so you don't have to memorize it, but browse through it and use it as a reference when wondering, "Is there a better way to...?"

Comment: Thank you for the link. I attached a gdb debugger to my code and printed the connection pointer it reveiled a px = 0 and pn = {pi_  = 0x0} so I think it returning a null pointer I guess

Comment: The reason you want to check for a null pointer right off the bat is a `shared_ptr` generally takes a bit of work to accidentally make null later as long as you are still holding a handle. I don't see any signs of mistakes that typically lead to destroying the pointer while it's still in use, so it's a lot more likely that you didn't get a valid pointer right from the get-go. You can easily eliminate that with a `if (!conncetion) {throw std::runtime_error("couldn't connect!"); }` and seeing if... OK, you just handled that with the debugger.

Comment: At this point I have to step back because I don't know RabbitMQ nearly well enough (or at all) to offer guidance on how to debug connection problems. I'd start with the usual, confirming the address and port and ensuring no firewalls are in the way, though.

Comment: I changed the code a little bit where I have a seperate initialization function that return the connection pointer and I eliminated the connection attribute from the Receiver class. I think it's not the solution but it's a workaround that actually works.